# How to join rows from two separate SQL query outputs

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets look at the following table:

```
Name    TIMESTAMP   STATUS

Task1   01-01-2019  COMPLETE
Task1   01-01-2019  COMPLETE
Task2   01-01-2019  COMPLETE
Task3   02-01-2019  NOT COMPLETE
Task4   01-01-2019  COMPLETE    
Task4   02-01-2019  COMPLETE
```

What I want the output to be like is:

```
Date              TaskName    How many completed?

January stats     Task1           2
February stats    Task2           1
Day 1 of march    Task3           0
Day 2 of march    Task4           1
Day 3 of march    Task1           0
```

Basically, I want the output table to show the total count of completed per task for each month before the current month, then on the following rows it shows the completed task count for each day in that month. Currently, I have got two separate output tables where one shows total completed task count for every month, then another output table that shows the total completed task count for each day in the current month. How can I join these two?

Comment: If you already have tables that contain the expected data, all that is left to do is to `UNION ALL` : `SELECT dt, taskname, cnt_completed FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT dt, taskname, cnt_completed FROM table2`

Comment: None of the data has March dates.  How is the March information calculated?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm sorry, I should have added more data in the first table - they are examples shown so that it is easier to see the format of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
with c as 
(
select timestamp, taskname, count(status) as Counter from your_table
group by date, name )
select timestamp as date, name as TaskName, Counter as HowManyCompleted
from c
```